# How to move to previous version of stack using cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

**Usecase**

I have cloudformation template with resources and lambda functions . Usually the cloudformation will rollback the stack when there is failure in creating it.

But what if i had pushed some resources or lambda functions with wrong logic or with less configurations . In such case i want to rollback the stack to previous working stack.

I Know i have `rollback triggers` to monitor my stack and trigger alarms. But i want to do it manually because, what if i had missing that test scenario and because of that the alarms not triggered.

Is it possible with cloudformation ?

Thanks
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Just update with the previous version of your deployment. If you use git or other version control it should be easy to just checkout the previous version and update with that one.

Answer (score 11):

No you can't do that with Cloudformation.

Your CD pipeline should keep track of any code builds and template configuration and you should rollback with old/archived code by pushing out a new stack with that old code.

Comment: Is this answer still valid?

Comment: Yes it is. This should be marked as an Answered post.